# How to draw decision boundary in SVM sklearn data in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm, svc

I am reading email data from training set and creating train_matrix, train_labels and test_labels. Now how do I display decision boundary using matplot in python. I am using svm of sklearn. There are online example for pre given data sets through iris. But plot fails on custom data. Here is my code

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier-plot.py", line 115, in <module>
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 260 into shape (150,1750)
```

Code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from sklearn import svm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


def make_Dictionary(root_dir):
    all_words = []
    emails = [os.path.join(root_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(root_dir)]
    for mail in emails:
        with open(mail) as m:
            for line in m:
                words = line.split()
                all_words += words
    dictionary = Counter(all_words)
    list_to_remove = dictionary.keys()

    for item in list_to_remove:
        if item.isalpha() == False:
            del dictionary[item]
        elif len(item) == 1:
            del dictionary[item]
    dictionary = dictionary.most_common(3000)

    return dictionary



def extract_features(mail_dir):
    files = [os.path.join(mail_dir,fi) for fi in os.listdir(mail_dir)]
    features_matrix = np.zeros((len(files),3000))
    train_labels = np.zeros(len(files))
    count = 0;
    docID = 0;
    for fil in files:
      with open(fil) as fi:
        for i,line in enumerate(fi):
          if i == 2:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
              wordID = 0
              for i,d in enumerate(dictionary):
                if d[0] == word:
                  wordID = i
                  features_matrix[docID,wordID] = words.count(word)
        train_labels[docID] = 0;
        filepathTokens = fil.split('/')
        lastToken = filepathTokens[len(filepathTokens) - 1]
        if lastToken.startswith("spmsg"):
            train_labels[docID] = 1;
            count = count + 1
        docID = docID + 1
    return features_matrix, train_labels



TRAIN_DIR = "../train-mails"
TEST_DIR = "../test-mails"

dictionary = make_Dictionary(TRAIN_DIR)

print "reading and processing emails from file."
features_matrix, labels = extract_features(TRAIN_DIR)
test_feature_matrix, test_labels = extract_features(TEST_DIR)


model = svm.SVC(kernel="rbf", C=10000)

print "Training model."
features_matrix = features_matrix[:len(features_matrix)/10]
labels = labels[:len(labels)/10]
#train model
model.fit(features_matrix, labels)

predicted_labels = model.predict(test_feature_matrix)

print "FINISHED classifying. accuracy score : "
print accuracy_score(test_labels, predicted_labels)







##----------------

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
# data since we want to plot the support vectors
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
X = features_matrix
y = labels
svc = model.fit(X, y)
#svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X, y)

# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = y[:].min() - 1, y[:].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# title for the plots
titles = ['SVC with linear kernel']



Z = predicted_labels#svc.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.title(titles[0])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Added the plot command and error traceback.

Comment: Are you following any tutorial? If yes, please link it here.

Comment: The plotting code seems to be based on the scikit-learn documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html
The example you follow uses feature vectors of dimension 2. You have feature vectors of dimension 3000. This would not fit easily.

Answer (score 2):

In the [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html) that you were following `Z` is computed by applying the classifier to a set of feature vectors generated to form a regular `NxM` grid. This makes the plot smooth.

When you replaced

```
Z = svc.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

with

```
Z = predicted_labels
```

you replaced this regular grid with the predictions taken on your dataset. The next line failed with an error since it could not reshape an array of size `len(files)` to an `NxM` matrix. There is no reason `len(files) = NxM`.

There is a reason why you could not follow the tutorial directly. Your data dimension is 3000, so your decision boundary would be a 2999-dimensional hyperplane in a 3000-dimensional space. This is not easy to visualize.

In the tutorial the dimension is 4 and it is reduced to 2 for visualization.
The best way to reduce the dimension of your data depends on the data. In the tutorial we just pick the first two components of the 4-dimensional vector.

Another option that works well in many cases is to use Principal Component Analysis to reduce the dimension of data.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
pca.fit(features_matrix, labels)
reduced_matrix = pca.fit_transform(features_matrix, labels)
model.fit(reduced_matrix, labels)
```

Such model can be used for 2D visualization. You can just follow the tutorial directly and define

```
Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

#### A complete but not a very impressive example

We do not have access to your email data, so for illustration we could just use random data.

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# initialize algorithms and data with random
model = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001,C=100.0)
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
U = rng.rand(200, 2000)
v = (rng.rand(200)*2).astype('int')
pca.fit(U,v)
U2 = pca.fit_transform(U,v)
model.fit(U2,v)

# generate grid for plotting
h = 0.2
x_min, x_max = U2[:,0].min() - 1, U2[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = U2[:,1].min() - 1, U2[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(
    np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
    np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# create decision boundary plot
Z = s.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
contourf(xx,yy,Z,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
scatter(U2[:,0],U2[:,1],c=v)
show()
```

Would produce a decision boundary that does not look very impressive.

[image: decision boundary obtain by reducing 2000 dimensions to 2]

Indeed the first two principal components capture just about 1% of the information contained in the data

```
>>> print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_) 
[ 0.00841935  0.00831764]
```

If now you introduce just a little bit of carefully disguised asymmetry you would already see an effect.

Modify the data to introduce shifts at just one coordinate randomly selected for each feature

```
random_shifts = (rng.rand(2000)*200).astype('int')
for i in range(MM):
    if v[i] == 1:
        U[i,random_shifts[i]] += 5.0
```

And applying PCA you would get somewhat more informative picture.

[image: decision boundary obtain by reducing 2000 dimensions to 2 after positive instances were randomly shifted]

Note that here the first two principal components already explain about 5% of the variance and the red part of the picture contains many more red points than blue ones.

Comment: could you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50334915/2508414